# View not found in production, works fine locally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I am deploying my app using Web Deploy to an IIS server. Everything works fine on my machine, but when I try to access one of my pages on production, Its returning a 500 error.

I can see that the page is throwing an `InvalidOperationException`.

```
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Edit' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Device/Edit.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Edit.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Edit.cshtml
```

The View definitely exists in one of the searched folders.

[image]

I tried doing a full clean/rebuild, and Visual Studio restart, but I still get this exception. If I run in release mode on my dev machine, the page works.

It seems that Web Deploy isn't compiling this view properly, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by dragging my view file into my `Shared` views folder. MVC has able to find the view in the shared folder. I then dragged the file back to it's original folder, and everything continued to work.

Comment: this worked for me, after dragging back and forth the commit changes showed it had a content remove set in the csproj file    

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="Views\Device\edit.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>